# how to setup and deployment process

Tags: c#, .net, xml

```
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"E:\NewFolder\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\QuestionFile.xml")
```

In my application i have read a xml file which is location in a specific location in my pc but now i want to deploy my application now when i rum my exe and install in other pc i get error that **read error** of xml file so what should i do for that.
like that i have used to read the xml file.

I would really appreciate if someone helps me out!
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could include the XML in the same folder as your program. In the code, build up the string dynamically, using the following to get the name of the folder the program is currently executing from:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

All you need to do after that is append the name of your XML file with `Path.Combine` or appending to the string.

**Edit:**

(You'll need to include references to `System.IO` and `System.Reflection`).

You could create the string holding the path separately, then use that for creating your reader:

```
string xmlLocation = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "QuestionFile.xml");
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xmlLocation);
```

Remember if you're running this in debug in VS, this will point to your debug directory so make sure a copy of the XML file is in there.

Comment: i have already included xml file in application folder of setup and deployment.how to build string dynamically

Comment: @SameerShaikh Glad to hear it. Please consider accepting my answer if I helped.

Answer (score 0):

Can you package the questions.xml with the EXE as embedded resource?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you have two options:

1) include the xml inside your solution as an embedded resource, and read it using GetManifestResourceStream. [Here's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexdan/archive/2007/12/19/loading-embedded-resources-in-c-using-getmanifestresourcestream.aspx) more info on how to do it.

2) Include it in the solution and set the file's Build Action to Content. Then in your MSI installer package you can include that project's "Content" output. This means the file will end up included as a separate physical file located in the application's installation path.
See [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766795.aspx) for more details. Step 2 shows how to add different outputs.

Comment: how can i do this, i don't have any idea about this,i have already included xml file in application folder of setup and deployment.how to do please provide me sample code for the same.

Comment: Is that file read-only to your application or does it edit and save it back?